# I can't identify partition when installing ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, installation, info

I am installing Ubuntu 12.04 and when you set how much for each OS, it doesn't say what is on each side. So i can't tell which side is Vista and which side is Ubuntu. I am assuming the left side is Ubuntu but I am not sure.

It used to have a colored bar with info on the bar but now it is a white strip and I can't tell.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpfull to edit your question and specify how you are installing it in detail. But I'm guessing your option was to "install alongside windows". In that case I believe that the existing partion (windows) is the left one.